# nginx not parsing regex well

Tags: regex, nginx, query-string

I have found following RegEx in one of nginx configuration file.

Here is this.

```
location ~ ^/(\w+)$ {
    //some comments and code
}
```

and

```
location ~ ^/(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
    //some comments and code
}
```

I don't know what is the meaning is for above regex. as per my understanding it is parsing my url which is containing single '/' character in query string, but some of my url has containing multiple '/' (slash) in a query string like '/auth/gmail/callback/', this url is ignored by above regex. How Do I right regex which is accept my this urls.

Thanks.

Comment: Second location will match `/auth/gmail/callback/`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, thanks for reply. may be some other problem with my config file, I have check this, some url works some not, BTW thanks for reply